# Recursive sequence with different starting term

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence given by $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}$.

1. Show that $a_n$ is constant if $a_0=2$
2. Show that it's increasing for $a_0\in(-1,2)$ and decreasing for $a_0\in [-2,-1)$ or $2<a_0$.
3. Determine the convergence of the sequence and evaluate the limit for the case $-1<a_0<2$.

I have done 1.

For 2. So far, I have that :

If $-1<a_0<2$, then $1<2+a_n<4$. But I got stuck here. I suppose I should prove that $a_{n+1}-a_n\geq 0$, but I don't see how. Any help is welcome.

Comment: There is a mistake in the problem. Let $a_0=-1.5$. Then $a_1=\sqrt{0.5}\approx 0.707$. But you know that for $a_n\in(-1,2)$ the sequence is increasing.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is a numerical calculation for several starting conditions.
[image]

Notice that for $a_0\ge -2$ you get $a_1\ge 0$. The equality for $a_1$ occurs for $a_0=-2$. So for any negative initial condition $a_1>a_0$, therefore you can reduce the problem to only positive initial conditions.

Then we want to check when $a_n$ is increasing or decreasing. I would use the ratio test:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\sqrt\frac{2+a_n}{a_n^2}$$
Calculate when is this ratio equal to $1$, then see for what $a_n$ is the value greater or smaller than $1$.